# How to reference a file in my nginx.conf

Tags: nginx

There is an example in the Nginx Beginner's Guide [1](https://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#conf_structure) that shows how to redirect requests for certain file types to a specific location:

```
location ~ \.(gif|jpg|png)$ {
    root /data/images;
}
```

Suppose I wanted to do this for a list of maybe a hundred different file extensions.  It would be really ugly to write it all in that same line.  Is there a way I can read the conditional argument in from a file?

External file FILE_EXTENTIONS.txt:

```
txt
data
jpg
mp3
midi
png
xml
csv
...
```

And then in my nginx.conf:

```
location ~ \.(open(FILE_EXTENSIONS.txt))
    root /data/images;
}
```

The main thing is I want to be able to read from a long list inside the nginx.conf

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to specify the file extensions which are not in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out it is as simple as including the file at the top and the config file automatically inherited the variables/directives.

For example:

```
include filetype.rules;
```